# Optimize a value from an unknown function based on multiple variables

Tags: statistics, optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms

If we have a set of variables that are fed into an unknown function that produces some output value - How can we attempt to optimize this output value, given that we have a large set of discrete samples for these variables, and a corresponding output value for each time step ?

Comment: Look up "derivative-free optimization". There exist some helpful heuristics along the lines of trust-region methods.

Comment: I would also like to comment that this question is closely related to "convex bandits", a hot area in machine learning research.